# Flood Card Question

Tags: forbidden-island

I’ve drawn 1 of my 2 flood cards. My first card changed the water level to 3. So do I now draw 1 flood card for a total of 2? Or do I draw 2 more for a total of 3?

Comment: You've either mixed decks together or you're drawing from the wrong one.

Answer (score 7):

The Water Level changes when you draw a Waters Rise! Card from the treasure deck. Drawing from the flood deck never changes the Water Level. As the rules say:

> If you draw a Waters Rise! card, you do not get a replacement card.

So when you draw your treasure cards, if one of them is a Waters Rise! card, then you get only one more card.